# what is a good spot to add NSNotification in a UIViewController Category

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-category

I have a `UIViewController` Category, namely `UIViewController`(CategoryName) I do some method swizzling in "+load" of this category, now I want to know what might be a good place to add this category as an observer of a certain `NSNotification`.

I need a `viewController` that is in the view to respond to when a `notification` is posted. But I don't want to go into each `viewController` and it as an observer of a `Notification`. Thats why I was thinking this category might be a good place to do that.

Also if I do add this category as an observer, where would be a good place to remove itself as an observer?

Answer (score 0):

You should add itself as an observer when it becomes part of the view, in the `viewDidLoad` method, and remove it when another view controller becomes the active view controller

```
[oldVC presentViewController:newVC animated:YES completion:^{ 

       [notificationCenter removeObserver:oldVC];

}];
```